# Not allowed to start service Intent app in on background

Tags: android

This is one of the most annoying android errors ever.

I've one service in my app that must run always that user is running the app.
Since android doesn't allow me to have a background service always on, and to have a foreground service on i must keep an annoying notification to the user. I turn on and turn off the service as the user goes background or foreground.

So, In a "pseudocode" I do:

```
app went background? 
is the service working? yes! -> keep running it : no! -> turn off
app went foreground?
is the service on? yes! -> do nothing : no! -> turn service on
```

The problem is when the user goes foreground and background very quickly.
In this situation the app call the method `startService()` to start the service, but before the method finishes user goes background then i get:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.tomatedigital.instagramgiveawaywinner/com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.service.MyService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{78dfb43 u0a139 TPSL bg:+2m52s319ms idle change:cached procs:1 seq(203,203,203)}
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1592)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1547)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:664)
       at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.activity.AdsAppCompatActivity.onResume(SourceFile:310)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1434)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7304)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3993)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4033)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

The most annoying think is i can't block user to go background, neither can catch this exception since it is thrown asynchrounously bys some android service wake up routine

HOW CAN I DEAL WITH IT

i would say 0,1% of my users go in this situation (is a few users but is a very annoying error)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need a service if you only want it running while the app is in the foreground. Why not just use a Thread?

Comment: read again... i do need a service

Comment: The whole point of a service is that it runs when your activity is in the background. But you're only using the service when your app is in the foreground...which means you don't need a service.

Comment: Service are used when apps are in background or not running. Why do you want a service when the app is running? I would suggest to change the architecture of your app. Or maybe I am missing something why do you need a service when the app is in FOREGROUND? Threads can handle any tasks that needs to be done when the app is running and in foreground.

Comment: read the text... the question isn't if i need or not a service. is how to handle the exception thrown

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: didn't find any solution....

Answer (score 1):

`Android Version >= Oreo` has limited background activities.

Use start -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    startForegroundService(your_new_intent_to_service);
}else {
    startService(your_new_intent_to_service);
}
```